# Noob Kubuntu/Linux user here. Need help step-by-step installation for p5.js and how to set up for it to work

Tags: kubuntu

I'm in desperate need help installing p5.js and making it work on my linux kubuntu os for school. 
I tried to look for videos on youtube on how to install p5.js on linux but failed to find anything and that fully explain how to install it.

I found this: https://github.com/processing/p5.js-editor/issues/250 but I struggle to understand what the poster meant to do "chmod +x" I tried to google it and got lost in it.

I'm new to linux os and have only been able to install programs using Sudo apt-get install or install programs through "app" store called Discover that came on Kubuntu.

I have no idea how to install programs using the zip-method. I downloaded the p5.js zip and unzipped it on the download folder but nothing happened... can someone please help me and provide a fully noob-proof instructions on how to get p5.js running on linux?

Thanks!

Comment: From your link: "download the Linux version, unzip, `chmod +x` the executable then you can run"

Comment: uhmm.... I know! but I don't know what the person meant by "chmod +x"

Comment: if you `man chmod` you'll see the [reference] manual page for `chmod` which will tell you "chmod - change file mode bits", ie. it adds execute (+x) permissions to the file that follows the command.  If you're unsure, my suggestion would be `man chmod` to help you better understand what is required, ie. view manual page for the command.  School is for learning, and you learn more if not spoon-fed (you can't learn by copy/paste)

Comment: the hmod +x is to give the downloaded file execute permission so you can run it. it can also be done by right clicking on the file go to properties then the permissions tab and click the box that says allow executeing file as program

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong... am i suppose to be doing this at the terminal? It doesnt seem to work the "chmod +x" https://imgur.com/a/fJ3j0Jk

Comment: i'm also not able to do this by right clicking the file and go to properties, the person tab doesnt have "allow executing file as program" https://imgur.com/a/DH9KT5R

Comment: in the file folder there is a file called p5 that is the executable so if you do it from the term it should be "chmod +x p5" just drop the "-linux" as there is no file called "p5-linux"

Comment: It's still not working, i tried to click on it to open but nothing happens.

Comment: well, this sucks... i just downloaded the program on my mac... i wanted to use my linux but its just not workout out.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've extracted the zip file, you'll need to give yourself permission to execute the executable file. The way to do this through the terminal is by running `chmod +x <name of file>`, or in this case, `chmod +x p5`. If you're not comfortable with that, Kubuntu's file manager has a way to do this through a GUI:

- [**right-click** the desired file to pull up the context menu, then select **properties**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Qeum.png)
- [under **permissions** select **"Is executable"**.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUhCz.png)

From there you can run it by either double-clicking the file, or running `./<name of executable file>` in a terminal. If it doesn't run at first, running it through a terminal will allow you to see the program's output. I should also note that this program seems to depend on the `libgconf-2-4` package, which I had to install manually.

At this point, you're done, but finding the file and manually executing every time you want to open it will quickly get tedious, so I would recommend moving the program to a more permanent location and adding a desktop file. A typical place to put unpackaged programs like this is `/opt`. Assuming all the files needed to run the program are in one folder, you can move the folder to `/opt` using `sudo mv ~/Downloads/<name of folder> /opt/<name of program>`.

Once the program is in a permanent location, we can use kmenuedit to create a desktop file. Hit `alt+f2` to pull up krunner and run `kmenuedit` from there. [Hit `alt+f2` to pull up krunner and run `kmenuedit` from there.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qzpza.png)

Select the "Development" category, then "New Item...", then enter the Item name.
The only field you *need* to fill from there is the command field, in which you would put `/opt/<name of program>/<name of executable file>`. Save the changes, and quit kmenuedit.